# Resizing a non-editable textarea

Tags: javascript, resize, textarea

I have two textareas in my web-page.
The first one is not-editable (read only) & the one below it is editable.
I want the read-only textarea to adjust its height automatically depending on its content.

The content for that textarea comes from a database.
If the content is of one line then the height should adjust & if it is of multiple lines then the height should adjust accordingly.

How can I achieve this ?? I want JavaScript & no JQuery.

Comment: Please do not hesitate to post what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I just googled to check for existing solutions and http://www.impressivewebs.com/textarea-auto-resize/ looks decent. The idea is to create hidden `div` which will let you measure the height of text input in your textarea. Remeber to have the same font styling in both the textarea and the div. With this in mind you can either translate that few lines of jquery into pure js or write it by yourself using this idea.

Comment: Thanx !! I have already tried this, but, it does not work for me !